# How do I pass a struct as an argument in pthread in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, pthreads

How do I pass a struct as an argument in pthread in c:

```c
    void * aFunction (aStruct1 *theStruct1, aStruct2 *theStruct2, aStruct3 *theStruct3){
        printf("%s", theStruct1->text);
    }
    
    pthread_t thread[2];
    pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, aFunction, "how do i pass all the struct argument here (theStruct1, theStruct2 , theStruct3)");
    pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, aFunction, "how do i pass all the struct argument here  (theStruct1, theStruct2 , theStruct3)");
    pthread_join(thread[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[2],NULL);
```

I have tried calling it as so with no result:

```c
    void * aFunction (aStruct1 *theStruct1, aStruct2 *theStruct2, aStruct3 *theStruct3){
        printf("%s", theStruct1->text);
    }
    
    pthread_t thread[2];
    pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, aFunction(theStruct1, theStruct2 , theStruct3), NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, aFunction(theStruct1, theStruct2 , theStruct3), NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[2],NULL);
```

Comment: You appear to need to be able to pass 3 structs to your function, not just 1.

Comment: The docs for `pthread_create` say `aFunction` must take a single `void*` as its argument.

Comment: ... where both "single" and "`void*`" are important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread start function passed to `pthread_create` *must* take a single `void *` argument.

Since you're passing in multiple structs, you'll need to define an additional struct which contains all data expected by the thread function and pass a pointer to that.

```
struct thread_args {
    aStruct1 *s1;
    aStruct2 *s2;
    aStruct3 *s3;
};

void *aFunction (void *p){
    struct thread_args *args = p;
    printf("%s", args->s1->text);
    return NULL;
}

struct thread_args args[] = {
    { theStruct1, theStruct2, theStruct3 },
    { theStruct1, theStruct2, theStruct3 }
};
pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, aFunction, &args[0]);
pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, aFunction, &args[1]);
```

Comment: perfectly explained thank you